# How to write linear activation function in Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I want use linear activation at my output layer.
I currently use `model.add(...)` to add layer.
I know how to use other activation function (for example sigmoid function, you can use `model.add(...,activation = "sigmoid")`. But my question is I simply don't want any activation function. That is I want **w•x** as my output from model, instead of a(**w•x**) where a is activation function. what should I do? Will simply do not include `activation`  work?

Comment: if you don't specify the activation parameter the default activation is linear. otherwise, you can manually define it with activation = "linear"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own activation function which returns what it takes.

```py
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
from keras.layers import Activation

def custom_activation(x):
    return x

get_custom_objects().update({'custom_activation': Activation(custom_activation)})

model.add(...,activation = "custom_activation")
```

### Edit

As specified by @MarcoCerliani, No need to do above stuff. Below both statements uses `linear` activation function.

```py
model.add(...,activation = "linear")

model.add(...)
```